# Powershell CSV import / row expansion behavior question

Tags: powershell

I'm still green on PowerShell - I wanted to understand if the following behavior is intended, or a bug, or a setting I turned on by mistake (happening in PS 5.1 and 7):

1. Create a CSV called c:\temp\users.csv with the following rows:

```
First,Last,Username
Bob,Smith,rsmith
Liz,Taylor,ltaylor
```

2. Run the following Powershell:

```
$users = import-csv c:\temp\users.csv

## this line works as I'd expect, pulling a column value from CSV:
foreach ($user in $users) { write-host Username is: $user.Username }
## output:
# Username is: rsmith
# Username is: etaylor

## but it behaves differently if the value touches other text, it expands to the full row array:
foreach ($user in $users) { write-host User path is: \\server\users\$user.Username }
## output:
# User path is: \\server\users\@{FirstName=Bob; LastName=Smith; Username=rsmith}.Username
# User path is: \\server\users\@{FirstName=Liz; LastName=Taylor; Username=etaylor}.Username

## and I figured out a work around:
foreach ($user in $users) { write-host User path is: ("\\server\users\",$user.Username -join "") }
## output:
# User path is: \\server\users\rsmith
# User path is: \\server\users\etaylor
```

I did a Write-Host here just to showcase, but I might use that type of behavior to pass a computed property value to a function etc. I know it's not the end of the world to do a -join, but is that expansion of the row to an array normal behavior under these conditions, or am I missing something? Also if there's a shorter syntax to combine inline, please share.

Thanks/sorry for such a nube question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subexpression operator `$()` inside a string, otherwise powershell may not know if you want to print entire $user variable and .Username string or Username property of $user object. 
Also, I'd suggest to start using Write-Information instead of Write-Host. 
Anyway, this should work: 
`write-host "User path is: \\server\users\$($user.Username)"`